# Self-Hosting GitLab on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

We are maintaining a Docker Swarm Implementation on AWS, using multiple EC2 instances to fuel the swarm.

Now we want to migrate our Gitlab repositories to a self-hosed Gitlab within our AWS VPC.

Hence I’m wondering which is one the better solution to self-host Gitlab on AWS:

1. self-host Gitlab on AWS using the AWS AMI or
2. Self-host gitlab on AWS using the regular Docker image provided by Gitlab and run it on any Linux AMI

Does anybody have have ever tried both solutions to compare them. 
The AWS AMI seems easier on first glance but there might be any disadvantages to using it over the native Docker image from Gitlab like updating to newer versions of Gitlab etc.

Many thanks in advance

A

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your team wants to maintain the service. You'll still need all the other services, RDS, S3, NFS, so maintain EC2 instances in ASG's or docker swarm? It's entirely based on how comfortable each team is with those respective technologies. Since are comfortable running Docker Containers, assuming since you are running Swarm, then running the Gitlab instances as containers should be relatively straightforward.

[You may not want to use AWS's EFS](https://medium.com/@aloisbarreras_18569/architecture-overview-of-gitlab-on-aws-d260c16a2ad7)

> There are many documented issues from GitLab users using EFS. The following are the warnings from the GitLab team

[Here is a blog post on fully automating EC2 with Terraform, Packer and Ansible](https://medium.com/@aloisbarreras_18569/automating-running-gitlab-on-aws-with-terraform-packer-and-ansible-bf1c8724ebea)

[Gitlab AWS Reference Architecture.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/university/high-availability/aws/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @strongjz, does that mean, it’s all the same and doesn’t matter if we run the AMI machine or the native Docker Image - notwithstanding the other parts you mentioned (RDS, S3 etc)?

Comment: Scaling, operations and costs are 3 factors to consider. Docker image is gonna be cheaper than ami the upgrade process is going to be cycle the asg or doing a docker service update, which both should be automated anyway. So cost and operations are your choices here. IDK the upgrade schedule of the ami or the image so no difference from my perspective really. Cost is the last factor then.